# Gradle build faild app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

How to resolve this issue. i dont know why i am getting this error

[![

```html
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT: libpng error: Read Error
AAPT: libpng error: Read Error
AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
AAPT: libpng error: Read Error
AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 6.679 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDYYb.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDYYb.png)

Comment: i tried Build >Cleaning project so many times

Comment: i have add log details please check it

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

**Took below steps that solved problem:**

1. Cut-paste the image on desktop.
2. Opened it in an editor saved it as png. without renaming the file name.
3. Copy-pasted the .png image into the drawable folder.

Now , You can use cruncherEnabled.

> Returns true if the PNGs should be crunched, false otherwise.

```
android 
{ 
aaptOptions
  {
 cruncherEnabled = false
  } 
}
```

Comment: Just try to do this your log shows "AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file" so this is the way to solve.

Answer (score 0):

the error comes because of the `png` file you have added to the `drawable` folder.this was the problem android studio was pointing. so you have to change the file extension using paint.net tool (proper way) or any other tool you know, then upload it to the `drawable` folder.

sometimes downgrading gradle build tools to `1.2.3` solved  problem of Crunching `png` error but on 1.5.0 problem continues.

happy coding.